# C# - Windows Phone 8, how can I start animation or storyboard first before I changed the visibility of an Element

Tags: c#, animation, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a question, how can I make an animation running first before the visibility changed on an XAML element?
The situation should be like this.

```
<Grid Name=Header Visiblity="visible">
   <Grid.Resources>
      <Storyboard x:Name="HeaderGridUp">
           <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
           Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderGrid">

                 <EasingDoubleKeyFrame Value="30" KeyTime="00:00:02">
                     <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                        <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                     </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                 </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>

            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
       </Storyboard>

       <Storyboard x:Name="HeaderGridDown">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
            Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderGrid">

                  <EasingDoubleKeyFrame Value="30" KeyTime="00:00:02">
                       <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                           <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                       </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                   </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>

             </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
   </Grid.Resources>
</Grid>
```

```
<Grid Name=Items Visiblity="collapsed">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="ItemsGridUp">
              <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
               Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsGrid">

                   <EasingDoubleKeyFrame Value="30" KeyTime="00:00:02">
                       <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                       </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                   </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>

              </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
          </Storyboard>

          <Storyboard x:Name="ItemsGridDown">
              <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
               Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsGrid">

                   <EasingDoubleKeyFrame Value="30" KeyTime="00:00:02">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                              <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                   </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>

                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
           </Storyboard>
     </Grid.Resources>
</Grid>
```

In my case, I would like an animation that move like Fade in and Fade out, that's why I make two storyboard each grid. First thing that I want my app run is.
The current state of `HeaderGrid` is visible, and when I touch a button, this grid will be going up and the visibility changed to collapsed. After that, the `ItemsGrid` will be going up change it's visibility and then going up replacing the `HeaderGrid` original place. Then I do the revert of the exact thing.
Can I possible doing that? and I would like to do it in code behind.
Any answer will be appreciated. :)
Thank You.

Regards,

Budi Prasetyo

Comment: Hi Budi Prasetyo, did you got solution for this. I need similar animation where I have to animate before the visibility changed on Grid. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

where you were supposed to add the visibility code in c#, u start a dispatchertimer with interval equal to your animations length and when the timer ticks change the visibility

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,x); //length of your animation in seconds
```

in main()

```
{
   timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
}
```

and the event handler for the tick

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop();
    element.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //or Collapsed
}
```

and where you're supposed to change the visibility of the element, just start the timer

```
timer.Start();
```

hope it helps :) and not too late ;)

Answer (score 0):

Once you set the Visibility of any element to Collapsed, you will not be able to see any animation, because the element is already collapsed. I just had this issue myself, wanting to ease out when items disappear from a list. My solution was to add another property to my ViewModel, IsRemoving, then set this to true before removing the element. You can then bind the animation to the changing of IsRemoving property to run the animation before setting Visibility on the element.

You can do the trick like this, using some async/await magic. This will delay for 1 second before actually removing the item. Because the delay is awaited, UI will not hang.

```
public async void RemoveItem(SomeItem item){
    IsRemoving = true;
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    <Your collection>.Remove(item);
    IsRemoving = false;
}
```

EDIT: IN XAML:

```
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsRemoving}" Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.LayoutTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseOut"></QuinticEase>
                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseOut"></QuinticEase>
                        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: Still confused @_@, can you give an example about using my code?
Actually, I've tried your solution. I've tried like this.
`HeaderGridUp.Begin();`
`await Task.Delay(5000);`
`HeaderGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;`
`ItemsGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;`
`ItemsGridUp.Begin();`
but. it doesn't work T_T. Is there any mistake that I made?

Comment: The thing is that I didnt start animation in code, its entirely XAML storyboard with a DataTrigger listening to the IsRemoving property to become true. Then, while animation runs (0-1 sec for example), you await a Task.Delay(1000) or so before removing the item. That way the animation runs on another property BEFORE item is removed

Comment: In my case, I don't use data template, I actually use it in a grid. So that's why I can't use your method T_T